# Why doesn't ActivatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe stream in all new route params

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have two main sections of my Angular app. One that is not controlled by the router, and the other piece that is controlled by the router. Well... when I inject `ActivatedRoute` into a component, only the component that is configured in the route config gets the correct `ActivatedRoute` info. The component that is present outside of the `router-outlet` (the sidebar) doesn't get any parameters when it subscribes to the `ActivatedRoute.paramMap`. But the component that is specified in the route config that gets passed to the `RouterModule.forRoot`, it gets the correct results when it subscribes to the `ActivatedRoute.paramMap`. No idea why one gets it correctly, and the other doesn't.

Any help?

Comment: Hard to tell from the info provided but if the component is outside of the router-outlet, you may need to check the `activatedRoute.parent` (or firstChild/children)? Or otherwise consider where in the ActivatedRoute hierarchy it sits.

Comment: I will check the parent tomorrow! I didn't know about that.